# Need to Copy 1 text file content into several other files

Tags: batch-file

I have a source file **blue01.environment** (text file)

I need to copy **the text** in this file and paste it into all of the below files, but saving them **with their original name**.

```
blue02.environment
yellow01.environment
yellow02.environment
yellow03.environment
purple01.environment
purple02.environment
...
```

Somebody could point me towards a batch command I could use?

Comment: The other files already have some content? Can it be deleted?

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory?

Comment: The files are in the same directory, but I can split them to have 1 master file in a directory, then all 79 files in a sub directory.  I will be copying the 79 files out of the directory when they are all copied and saved.

Comment: Also, the other files do have content in them, but yes I would like it all overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# the file you want the content to be copied
master=/your_dir/master_file

# get the content
content="$(cat $master)"

# loop the files .environment
for file in /your_dir/*.environment; do 
  # if the file is not the master file copy the content
  [ "$file" != "$master" ] && echo "$content" > "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```cmd
rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=." & rem // (path to root directory; `.` is current, `%~dp0.` is batch file parent)
set "_MASK=*.environment" & rem // (pattern to match files to process)
set "_MASTER=blue01.environment" & rem // (name of master file)

rem // Change to root directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    // Iterate over all matching files:
    for %%I in ("%_MASK%") do @(
        rem // Exclude master file to be overwritten:
        if /I not "%%~nxI" == "%_MASTER%" (
            rem // Copy master file onto current file:
            copy /Y "%_MASTER%" "%%~I" > nul
        )
    )
    rem // Return from root directory:
    popd
)
```